# Training GPT2 and Reformer from scratch

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am looking, for example, script/notebook to train GPT2 and Reformer model from scratch in German.
Something similar to :

> https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/blog/blob/master/notebooks/01_how_to_train.ipynb

I am trying to modify the same notebook but GPT2 doesn't seem to accept LinebyLineDataset or padding.

My Error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

~/anaconda3/envs/thesis_p1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, model_path)
    490                 self._past = None
    491 
--> 492             for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
    493 
    494                 # Skip past any already trained steps if resuming training

~/anaconda3/envs/thesis_p1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/notebook.py in __iter__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    226     def __iter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    227         try:
--> 228             for obj in super(tqdm_notebook, self).__iter__(*args, **kwargs):
    229                 # return super(tqdm...) will not catch exception
    230                 yield obj

~/anaconda3/envs/thesis_p1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py in __iter__(self)
   1128 
   1129         try:
-> 1130             for obj in iterable:
   1131                 yield obj
   1132                 # Update and possibly print the progressbar.

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    344     def __next__(self):
    345         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 346         data = self.dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    347         if self.pin_memory:
    348             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 47         return self.collate_fn(data)

~/anaconda3/envs/thesis_p1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py in __call__(self, examples)
     79 
     80     def __call__(self, examples: List[torch.Tensor]) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
---> 81         batch = self._tensorize_batch(examples)
     82         if self.mlm:
     83             inputs, labels = self.mask_tokens(batch)

~/anaconda3/envs/thesis_p1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py in _tensorize_batch(self, examples)
     96             if self.tokenizer._pad_token is None:
     97                 raise ValueError(
---> 98                     "You are attempting to pad samples but the tokenizer you are using"
     99                     f" ({self.tokenizer.__class__.__name__}) does not have one."
    100                 )

ValueError: You are attempting to pad samples but the tokenizer you are using (GPT2Tokenizer) does not have one.
```

Here is my current implementation:

Datasets looks like this (Million lines):

```
1   "09.05.2019, Flyer: Zeit für Perspektiven - Unterstützung im Haushalt durch professionelle Dienstleistungen"
2   %0A%0ADie Burg Werle (ca. 10 km von hier entfernt) war ein schwer einnehmbarer Schlupfwinkel.
3   %0A%0AHier, abseits der verkehrsreichen Straßen, liegt das idyllische Quellental, ein Naturdenkmal der besonderen Art.
4   ½ bis 1 Tasse (75–150 ml) HEITMANN Reine Citronensäure in ½ Liter Wasser geben und in den Wassertank der Maschine füllen.
5   %0% der anfallenden Kosten ergeben sich aus der Straßenbeleuchtung.
6   ¾ Parken während der Ladezeit in Fußgängerzonen, in denen das Be- oder Entladen für bestimmte Zeiten freigegeben ist.
```

First I train Sentence Piece Tokenizer:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sentencepiece as spm
paths = [str(x) for x in Path(".").glob("**/*.txt")]
arg='--input=deu-de_web-public_2019_1M-sentences.txt --model_prefix=m_test --vocab_size=52000'
spm.SentencePieceTrainer.train(arg)
```

Then I load my GPT2 tokenizer as below:

```
from transformers import GPT2TokenizerFast

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("./German",additional_special_tokens=["<s>","<pad>","</s>","<unk>","<mask>"], max_len=512)
```

Here is my GPT2 config and language Model:

```
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Config

# Initializing a GPT2 configuration
configuration = GPT2Config(vocab_size=52_000)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel(config=configuration)
```

The logic for Dataset Preparation:

```
from transformers import LineByLineTextDataset

dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path="./deu-de_web-public_2019_1M-sentences.txt",
    block_size=128,
)
from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling

data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False,
)
```

The training logic:

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./output",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_gpu_train_batch_size=64,
    save_steps=10_000,
    save_total_limit=2,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    prediction_loss_only=True,
)
trainer.train()
```

Comment: @cronoik I have added my current implementation and the stack trace. Hope it is clear.

Comment: You can't use the LineByLineTextDataset class with GPT2 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4122). Use `TextDataset` instead.